# Package 'vnc4server' has no installation candidate

Tags: apt, vnc

```
> sudo apt install vnc4server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package vnc4server is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'vnc4server' has no installation candidate
```

I don’t know why, but there is very little information about vnc4server on the Internet. It seems that no one uses this software. I can’t even find the source of this software.

WSL2 Ubuntu 22 LTS.

Comment: What do you need it for? It was [replaced by `tigervnc-standalone-server` many years ago](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=947604), and they removed the transitional packages after a couple of releases as usual.

Comment: @muru This docs (https://docs.minedojo.org/sections/getting_started/install.html#on-ubuntu-20-04) tell me install vnc4server.

Comment: Ah, then just install `tigervnc-standalone-server` instead. At the time Ubuntu 20.04 was released that's what you'd have actually got if you did `apt-get install vnc4server`

Comment: @muru Thanks you!